# Updating multiple labels from dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

I want to dynamically update and create labels from a dictionary (or list or variable).

How can I link/update the labels when the dictionary changes?

When the button is pressed it generates random values and stores them into a dict. Those values are used to create the labels in the init function.
How to keep those values up-to-date when the button is pressed?

```
import sys, random
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):
        self.updt = QtWidgets.QPushButton( 'Update' )
        mygroupbox = QtWidgets.QGroupBox('')
        myform = QtWidgets.QFormLayout()

        myDict = createValues.randomValues()
        for i, item in myDict.items():
            self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel( str( item['value'] ) )
            myform.addRow(self.label)
        mygroupbox.setLayout(myform)
        scroll = QtWidgets.QScrollArea()
        scroll.setWidget(mygroupbox)
        scroll.setWidgetResizable(True)
        scroll.setFixedHeight(400)
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.updt)
        layout.addWidget(scroll)

        self.updt.clicked.connect(lambda: self.changeValues() )

        self.show()

    def changeValues(self):
        self.myDict = createValues.randomValues()

class createValues():
    def randomValues():
        items = ['item1','item2','item3','item4']
        myData = {}

        for i in items:
            myData[i] = {}
            myData[i]['name'] = i
            myData[i]['value'] = random.uniform(0, 10)

        print(myData)
        return myData


app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
a_window = Window()
a_window.setGeometry(500, 300, 300, 400)
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Also, you don't need a class `createValues`, you could just have the function `randomValues`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would separate the layout (creating the labels in `init_ui`) from the "giving labels random values" logic.

In `init_ui`, we can create a defined number of `QLabel` and keep track of them in a list. Something like:

```
self.updt = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Update')
self.updt.clicked.connect(self.changeValues)  # no need for lamba

myform = QtWidgets.QFormLayout()
self.mylabels = []
for i in range(4):  # or better, define a constant like "NB_VALUES = 4" and use it
    label = QtWidgets.QLabel()
    myform.addRow(label)
    self.mylabels.append(label)
...
```

In `change_values`, we can put all the logic to fill the label with random values

```
def changeValues(self):
    self.myDict = randomValues()
    for item, label in zip(self.myDict.values(), self.mylabels):
        label.setText(str(item['value']))
```

To initialize the labels with a first value, you can simply call `self.changeValues()` at the end of `__init__`

Comment: I have one more question to this. Let's say the amount of values are changing over time (Aka number of labels).
How to add extra labels to the interface then? Because now that is still fixed inside the init.

Comment: You should be able to add more labels anytime with `myform.addRow` and `self.mylabels.append`.